# Можно ли получить геометрию зданий в yandex-maps-api?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Возможно ли в api получить геометрию зданий или других обьектов в yandex-maps-api?
т.е аналог https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#queryrenderedfeatures из mapbox, который позволяет по заданной области достать geojson (геометрия зданий, дорог и тд)

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время Яндекс такой возможности (геометрия зданий) не предоставляет. Точно также, как нельзя через API Яндекса получить геометрию населённых пунктов и прочих топонимов. Считайте, что это пока "эксклюзив" Яндекса, который они придерживают для внутренних нужд - своих приложений и сервисов.